# SQLite 3 - How to select the next value.. in the MIN() from the below code and how to automate it for all the next,next... values

Tags: sqlite

```sql
               MIN( CASE
                    WHEN Type = 435 THEN TimeStamp 
               END ) AS InTime,                   
               MIN( CASE
                    WHEN Type = 324 THEN TimeStamp 
               END ) AS OutTime
```

the above code uses min() to find the minimum value, how to find the next minimum value and how to get all the next.... values...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TimeStamp AS InTime
FROM MyTable
WHERE Type = 435
ORDER BY Timestamp;

SELECT TimeStamp AS OutTime
FROM MyTable
WHERE Type = 324
ORDER BY Timestamp;
```